# Angular - How do I parse the objects in inside event.path

Tags: angular, mouseevent

Now this is a complicated issue to explain, I will try my best.

I have a popover from which I want to uniquely identify a click event if it is from inside or outside the popover.

My first approach: I enveloped the entire popover with a `div` with an `id`, say "unique".

So, I bound the click event with a host listener for which I will get an event object. So, if I traverse the `event.path` --- *this contains an array of objects* --- inside one of the indexes of these objects lies a field `id`, which will give me the name of my `id`.

Note: this index will be always dynamic- but the `id` will be guaranteed in one of the index. I need to traverse till this `id`. Please help. I have attached some images for better visualization.

The host listener:

[image]

The event object:

[image]

By expanding this we get the unique parent id:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `path` property on an event is only available in Chrome, and is undocumented. You can use the equivalent [`composedPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath), but IE and Edge do not support this yet.

If you don't care about that support you can do something like this. See how I used `ViewChild` to get the correct element. It's better this way, so you don't need to use silly IDs:

```
@ViewChild('elementYouCareAbout',  {read: ElementRef}) element: ElementRef<any>;   

@HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
  const isInside = event.composedPath().includes(this.element.nativeElement);
}
```

Now if you do care about IE and Edge support, there is another way to check it, and that's by using the [`parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) property:

```
@ViewChild('elementYouCareAbout') element: ElementRef<any>;   

@HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
  let isInside = false;
  let target = event.target;
  while(target && !isInside) {
    isInside = this.element.nativeElement === target;
    target = target.parentElement;
  }

  // if inside than isInside is true
}
```

this code is not tested though, so be advised

Comment: The `path` property is now in Edge, still not in Mozilla

Comment: why not use:`this.element.nativeElement.contains(event.target as HTMLElement)`?:NOTE If we define the hostListener in the "popover" we can inject the ElementRef in the constructor and check if contains the event.target

Comment: @Eliseo yep, that's the way to do it